# How to flash stock ROM .DZ file on a semi-bricked LG Android phone?

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, stock-rom

Is it possible to flash a .DZ stock ROM on a LG Android phone (Doubleplay / C729 / Flip II) that doesn't fully load (T-Mobile logo repeats itself)? If yes, how exactly?

Details:

1. Recovery mode has no options, it only displays an unpacking icon for a few seconds.
2. USB debugging is not enabled.
3. USB connection with PC is stable and working.
4. A .DLL file is included with the .DZ file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this.

Where did you get the .dz file from?

You would have to ask the prividor to provide a .kdz file as well as the .dz file so you can flash with the KDZ Updater program.

Comment: The .DZ ROM is the only ROM for LG C729 (Doubleplay) that I was able to find, so there's no provider.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1287236) update tool? It should do the work if it can connect.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but it accepts only .KDZ files, not .DZ